# How do I get the maximum the maximum degree of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

For example applied to `y^2*x^3 + z^2+1` it should give `5` due to the  `y^2*x^3`component.

Answer (score 3):

```
Max[Total@*First /@ CoefficientRules[y^2*x^3 + z^2 + 1]]
```

> 5

This extracts rules for all coefficient combinations, ignores the constant multiplier for them, sums powers in each of them, and takes the largest sum.

Answer (score 1):

may be this will work in general. Did not test it fully

```
ClearAll[x,y,z];
p = y^2* x^3 + z^2 + 1;
Exponent[p /. {y -> x, z -> x}, x]

(* 5 *)
```

Comment: You could also automate the replacement of variables with `Exponent[p /. Alternatives @@ Variables@p -> x, x]`.

Comment: @kirma thanks for the nice hint.